# Frame wiping itself clean after each repaint

Tags: java, awt, repaint, thread-sleep

I didn't call super.paintMethod() in my paintMethod, yet, every time the code runs, it wipe the window clean for some reason. Any suggestions? Here's my code.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

        frame.repaint();

        Thread.sleep(250);
        P.x += 50;
        if (P.x == 450) {
            P.x = 0;
            P.y += 50;
        }
```

Comment: Show us the `paintComponent()` method you overrided.

Comment: What does it mean to override the paintComponent method?

Comment: This is the expected behaviour of painting, painting is destructive. On each paint cycle, the components are expected to completely repaint themselves. See [Painting and AWT and Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) and [Performing custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    frame.repaint();
```

Does it. By default `Component#paintComponent()` will render the background color on every repaint call.
Though if you override this method, and you don't call `super.paintComponent()`, this step is omitted, causing an overlap painting.

Comment: How do I override this method?

Comment: By extending a component, BTW this is Java 101 and more important than graphics. Study that instead.

Comment: What do you mean extend a component? how do i extend a componet?

Comment: As I said you are fairly raw in the principle concepts in Java, go back to your books.